# Network Programming: what happen if network disconnect after select and before send

Tags: c, networking, network-programming

I need to implement an timeout socket which the `send()`/`recv()` system calls should return after a timeout. And I think the standard method should be, call `select()`/`pool()` before `send()`/`recv()`. Below is the example code I copy from ffmpeg source code:

```
    int ff_network_wait_fd(int fd, int write)                                           
    {                                                                                
        int ev = write ? POLLOUT : POLLIN;                                              
        struct pollfd p = { .fd = fd, .events = ev, .revents = 0 };                     
        int ret;                                                                     
        ret = poll(&p, 1, 100);                                                      

        return ret < 0 ? ff_neterrno() : p.revents & 
               (ev | POLLERR | POLLHUP) ? 0 :     AVERROR(EAGAIN);
    }                                                                                

    int ff_network_wait_fd_timeout(int fd, int write, int64_t timeout, AVIOInterruptCB *int_cb)
    {                                                                           
        int ret;                                                                
        int64_t wait_start = 0;                                                 

        while (1) {                                                             
            if (ff_check_interrupt(int_cb))                                     
                return AVERROR_EXIT;                                            
            ret = ff_network_wait_fd(fd, write);                                
            if (ret != AVERROR(EAGAIN))                                         
                return ret;                                                     
            if (timeout > 0) {                                                  
                if (!wait_start)                                                
                    wait_start = av_gettime();                                  
                else if (av_gettime() - wait_start > timeout)                   
                    return AVERROR(ETIMEDOUT);                                  
            }                                                                   
        }                                                                       
    }

    static int tcp_write(URLContext *h, const uint8_t *buf, int size)           
    {                                                                           
        TCPContext *s = h->priv_data;                                           
        int ret;                                                                

        if (!(h->flags & AVIO_FLAG_NONBLOCK)) {                                 
            ret = ff_network_wait_fd_timeout(s->fd, 1, h->rw_timeout, &h->interrupt_callback);
            if (ret)                                                            
                return ret;                                                     
        }                                                                       
        ret = send(s->fd, buf, size, 0);                                        
        return ret < 0 ? ff_neterrno() : ret;                                   
    }
```

Seems that `tcp_write()` call `ff_network_wait_fd_timeout()` to prepare the environment. But it makes me so confusion that, if network cable unplugged after `ff_network_wait_fd()`(this should call `poll()` system call), should `send()` return `-1`, or still blocked? Thanks very much.

Comment: send() and recv() are system calls, not operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need poll() to implement a timeout for recv(). Just call setsockopt() with the option SO_RCVTIMEO and deal with the EWOULDBLOCK errno as a timeout.
2. You do need to use poll() for a send() timeout.
3. A broken TCP connection can only be detected by trying to write to it. There is no network event that triggers a poll() event.

Answer (score 0):

`send` will return normally, because it only puts data into the TCP send buffer.

The buffer data will be send by TCP protocol.